Connecting network namespaces indirectly through host by veth pairs
I am trying to connect two network namespaces indirectly by connecting each namespace to my host through a veth pair like below picture.

This is my script:
#! /bin/bash

sudo ip netns add NS1
sudo ip link add veth10 type veth peer name veth11
sudo ip link set veth11 netns NS1
sudo ip addr add 172.16.0.1/24 dev veth10
sudo ip netns exec NS1 ip addr add 172.16.0.2/24 dev veth11
sudo ip link set veth10 up
sudo ip netns exec NS1 ip link set veth11 up
sudo ip netns exec NS1 ip route add default via 172.16.0.1 dev veth11


sudo ip netns add NS2
sudo ip link add veth20 type veth peer name veth21
sudo ip link set veth21 netns NS2
sudo ip addr add 172.16.1.1/24 dev veth20
sudo ip netns exec NS2 ip addr add 172.16.1.2/24 dev veth21
sudo ip link set veth20 up
sudo ip netns exec NS2 ip link set veth21 up
sudo ip netns exec NS2 ip route add default via 172.16.1.1 dev veth21

sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

sudo ip netns exec NS1 ping -c 3 172.16.1.1
ping -c 3 172.16.1.2
sudo ip netns exec NS1 ping -c 3 172.16.1.2

sudo ip netns delete NS1
sudo ip netns delete NS2

but the last ping (sudo ip netns exec NS1 ping -c 3 172.16.1.2) fails (don't receive any icmp packets). What is the problem? I can ping host interfaces from NS1, and NS2 interfaces from host. Why I can't ping NS2 interfaces from NS1?
I know I should use a bridge, but I don't know why this is not working.
Thanks!
